# Remove <span style> tags around text with Vim

Tags: vim

Basically, I would like to turn stuff like this:

```
<span style="font-size: 1.1rem;">Lorem ipsum</span>
```

into this:

```
Lorem ipsum
```

In a whole document.

What's the fastest way of doing this with Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
:%s/<span style="[^"]*">\([^<]*\)<\/span>/\1/g
```

should do the trick. I'm not quite sure if you'd need to escape the capturing parentheses or not, though.

(Thanks Birei for the escaping)

Comment: You need to escape parentheses to create the group 1 used as `\1`. Also, with `%` range, `vim` will stop the command when substitution doesn't succeed. I don't know if it could be an issue for the OP, but using `:g` could be an alternative to it.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove all `<span ..>` tags, and leave the content, you could:

```
:%s/<span[^>]*>\([^<]*\)<.*/\1/
```

if you just want to do the substitution on those `<span..` with certain `style=".."`, you can just copy the `<span style="font-size: 1.1rem;">` put it before `\([^<]*\).....`

if your file is xml format, and your vim was armed with xml plugin, you could do it with macro(or `:g`), with xml plugin, `<localleader>d` deletes the surrounding tags and leave the text value.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `vim surround` plugin by `Tim Pope`.
it's very suitable for your needs.

> Surround.vim is all about "surroundings": parentheses, brackets,
>   quotes, XML tags, and more. The plugin provides mappings to easily
>   delete, change and add such surroundings in pairs.

http://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the same from the normal mode you might:

place the cursor somewhere between first and last bracket of the paired tags and copy what's inside the tag into register let's say `p`:

```
"pyit
```

then delete the whole pair tag:

```
dat
```

and then paste what's in the `p` register:

```
"pp
```

The advantage of this approach is that it would work for all pair tags. When recorded as macro you may get rid of many different tags by just finding the tag and running the macro.

Answer (score -2):

```
:%s/<span style="font-size: 1.1rem;">Lorem ipsum<\/span>/Lorem ipsum/g
```

Thanks

Comment: Not at all. First you forgot to escape the `/` in `</span>`, then this doesn't match anything other than "Lorem ipsum".

Comment: Ah i realise that it only matches Lorem ipsum, I read the request a little too specifically perhaps! I have added the escape :)..still would work if you need to search and replace something specific rather than just everything with that span style.